# Why is this route not routing through `page-router-outlet`?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to have a component that has an ActionBar and child components that are accessed by `page-router-outlet`.

My HTML for the parent component is as follows:

```
<ActionBar class="action-bar">
    <NavigationButton ios:visibility="collapsed" icon="res://menu" (tap)="onDrawerButtonTap()"></NavigationButton>
    <ActionItem icon="res://navigation/menu" android:visibility="collapsed" (tap)="onDrawerButtonTap()"
                ios.position="left">
    </ActionItem>
    <Label class="action-bar-title" text="Example Text"></Label>
</ActionBar>

<RadSideDrawer #drawer showOverNavigation="true" [drawerTransition]="sideDrawerTransition">
   <StackLayout tkDrawerContent>
        <MyDrawer [selectedPage]="'Settings'"></MyDrawer>
    </StackLayout>

   <StackLayout class="page page-content" tkMainContent>
        <page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
    </StackLayout>
</RadSideDrawer>
```

My `routing-module` for the parent component looks like:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {NativeScriptRouterModule} from 'nativescript-angular/router';

import {HomeComponent} from './home.component';
import {DashboardComponent} from '../dashboard/dashboard.component';
import {Dashboard2Component} from '../dashboard2/dashboard.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', component: DashboardComponent},
      {path: 'projects', component: Dashboard2Component},
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule {
}

export const routedComponents = [
  HomeComponent
];
```

However, when I route to `/projects`, it brings me to a new page with a new actionbar

[image: GIF Of routing gone wrong]

It's my understanding that this is because `page-router-outlet` creates a new page, that being said, I want to be able to navigate back from one child component back to the previous child component. Is this possible in {N}?

Comment: You can try using `<router-outlet>` instead of the `<page-router-outlet>`... The first one will not create a new page, only replace the contents inside the current one...

Comment: @AndersonIvanWitzke But if I do so, it will not allow me to press the back button in order to access the previous page

Answer (score 0):

Make the main template for your app as a component...

`app-template.component.html:`

```
<ActionBar class="action-bar">
    <NavigationButton class="action-item" icon="res://ic_menu" (tap)="toggleDrawer()"></NavigationButton>
    <StackLayout class="action-bar-title">
        <Label [text]="title"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</ActionBar>

<RadSideDrawer showOverNavigation="true">
    <ScrollView tkDrawerContent class="sidedrawer-center" tkDrawerClosed="onDrawerClosed" tkDrawerClosing="onDrawerClosing" tkDrawerOpened="onDrawerOpened" tkDrawerOpening="onDrawerOpening">
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout class="sidedrawer-header">
                <Label text="blah blah blah" class="text-left text-capitalize font-weight-bold text-primary" textWrap="true"></Label>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout class="sidedrawer-content">
                <GridLayout (tap)="closeDrawer()" nsRouterLinkActive="active" [nsRouterLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" [nsRouterLink]="['/']" class="sidedrawer-list-item" pageTransition="fade" rows="auto" columns="auto, *">
                    <Label class="sidedrawer-list-item-text" row="0" col="1" text="Home"></Label>
                </GridLayout>

                <GridLayout (tap)="closeDrawer()" nsRouterLinkActive="active" [nsRouterLink]="['/settings']" class="sidedrawer-list-item" pageTransition="fade" rows="auto" columns="auto, *">
                    <Label class="sidedrawer-list-item-text" row="0" col="1" text="Settings"></Label>
                </GridLayout>

            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <StackLayout tkMainContent class="page">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </StackLayout>
</RadSideDrawer>
```

`app-template.component.ts:`

```
import { Component, ViewChild, Input, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { RadSideDrawer, PushTransition } from "nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer";
import { RadSideDrawerComponent } from "nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer/angular";

@Component({
    selector: "app-template",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: './app-template.component.html'
})
export class AppTemplateComponent {
    canToggleDrawer: boolean = true;

    constructor() { }

    @Input() title: string = 'MyApp';

    @ViewChild(RadSideDrawerComponent) drawerComponent: RadSideDrawerComponent;
    drawer: RadSideDrawer;

    ngOnInit() {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.drawer = this.drawerComponent.sideDrawer;
        this.drawer.drawerTransition = new PushTransition();
    }

    toggleDrawer() {
        if (this.canToggleDrawer) {
            this.drawer.toggleDrawerState();
        }
    }

    closeDrawer() {
        this.drawer.closeDrawer();
    }
}
```

then on your child views, just call it as `<app-template>` and put your content inside it. This way, you can keep your drawer menu in one file only, and still be able to use the back buttons...